# Native Packager exception occurred

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

I am getting below exception while building phone gap application for blackberry 10.

```
[BUILD]   Populating application source
[BUILD]   Parsing config.xml
[BUILD]   Generating output files
[WARN]    Failed to find debug token
[INFO]    Info: Package created: C:\Ex\hello\build\simulator\HelloWorld.bar
[ERROR]   Error: bar1558418047103827107.MF, Invalid manifest version.
[ERROR]   Native Packager exception occurred
[WARN]    Failed to find debug token
[INFO]    Info: Package created: C:\Ex\hello\build\device\HelloWorld.bar
[ERROR]   Error: bar1882161790050252236.MF, Invalid manifest version.
[ERROR]   Native Packager exception occurred
```

Can any one help me plaese.

Comment: I am having hitting the same error with cordova 3.2 and blackberry10

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [BlackBerry 10 Webworks SDK](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/).

Make sure to restart your shell afterwards to have your environment variables updated.